# Androidアプリ上で「.mov」形式の動画を「.mp4」形式の動画に変換したい

Tags: android, unity2d

Android端末で「.mov」形式の動画をサポートしていないため、
アプリ上で「.mov」形式の動画を「.mp4」形式の動画に変換したいと考えております。
調べると「FFmpeg Unity Bind」という有料アセットを見つけたのですが、Android64bitの対応がされておらず、
サポートも終了しているような状態でしたので見送りました。

開発はUnityで行っています。
Unityの機能やネイティブの機能またはプラグインで変更は出来ますでしょうか。

Unity環境
2018.3.13f1

Comment: android 端末上で mov → mp4 に変換するんすか？　そんな電池食いそうなことを末端ユーザーにさせるなんてありえないっす。

Comment: 割とアプリは有るようです。[Top 8 Best Video Converters for Android to Convert MOV to MP4](https://videoconverter.wondershare.com/convert-mov/convert-mov-to-mp4-android.html), [MOV to MP4 Android – How to Convert MOV Files to MP4 for Android Q/Pie/Oreo](https://www.anymp4.com/converter/convert-mov-to-mp4-android.html) あとAndroid のAPIを自分で呼ぶとか。[AndroidでMediaCodecを使いFFmpegなしで動画を圧縮する方法（ライブラリあり）](https://qiita.com/yuya_presto/items/d48e29c89109b746d000), [MediaCodec を利用した動画作成](http://tokyo.supersoftware.co.jp/code/6104), [サポートされているメディア形式](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats?hl=ja)

Comment: https://github.com/tanersener/mobile-ffmpeg
というのを今実装しようとしているのですが、大量のUndefined symbolが出て
x-codeでビルドが通らない状況です
こちら何か原因などわかりますでしょうか。
libbz2、libc++、libiconv、libz、CoreMotion、GameController、VideoToolbox、Accelerateのシステムライブラリは追加しております。